# Puppeteer Select a paragraph by his classname

Tags: javascript, node.js, web-scraping, puppeteer

I want to select a p which is the only one with a classname. But why doesn't the javascript code work?

Note: I can't do elements[i].className =="test", because the class name changes every time I reopen the website.

When I run this in the console I get:

```
undefined
undefined
undefined
```

```js
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');

async function test() {
const browser = await puppeteer.launch({ headless: false, timeout: 0};
const page2 = await browser.newPage();
await page2.goto("localhost");
await page2.waitFor(2530);
const elements = await page2.evaluate(() => [...document.querySelectorAll('p')]);
for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
  if(elements[i].className){
    console.log(elements[i].innerText);
  }
}

}
test();
```

```html
<p>text1</p>
<p class="test">text2</p>
<p>text3</p>
```

Comment: Please share a working code snippet or a fiddleJs link where correct version of puppeteer is included.

Comment: I changed the javascript snippet. Is it correct now?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');

async function test() {
const browser = await puppeteer.launch({ headless: false, timeout: 0};
const page2 = await browser.newPage();
await page2.goto("localhost");
await page2.waitFor(2530);
const elements = await page2.evaluate(() => [...document.querySelectorAll('p')]);
for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
  if(elements[i].className){
    console.log(elements[i].innerText[]);
  }
}

}
test();
```

Change this line

```
console.log(elements[i].innerText[]);
```

to

```
console.log(elements[i].innerText);
```

And use this to return an array of paragraphs from the evaluate

```
 const textsArray = await page2.evaluate(
        () => [...document.querySelectorAll('p')].map(elem => elem.innerText)
    );
```

This will return an array of all the text from the paragraph tags or else you can manipulate map to return an objects inside array with their class name also,if you want both

Like This

```
const textsArray = await page2.evaluate(() => 
     [...document.querySelectorAll('p')].map(elem => 
      { return {class: elem.className,  text:elem.innerText}
     )
    );
```

Comment: It unfortunately doesn't . :/

Comment: Try it out Now @Finn K

Answer (score 0):

```
async function test() {

        const browser = await puppeteer.launch({ headless: false, timeout: 0};
        const page2 = await browser.newPage();
        await page2.goto("localhost");
        await page2.waitFor(2530);


        let elements = await page.$$('p');
        for (let i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
            let el_class = await page.evaluate(el => el.getAttribute('class'), elements[i]);
            console.log(el_class);
        }


}
```